# How do you set value of a cell depending if a match exists of another value in another column?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

The idea is a check-in / check-out system.

**Column A** 
loaner01 
loaner02 
loaner03

**Column C** 
in_stock 
in_stock 
out_of_stock

There's a Google Form that asks which loaner you want.  You select loaner02 and check out.  I want the Google script to now search for **loaner02** in column A, then change **in_stock** from column C to **out_of_stock**

I've only been able to figure out how to grab the response so I can set variable to **loaner02**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function checkOut(item) {
  var item=item || 'loaner03';//used for debugging
  if(item) {
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh=ss.getSheetByName('CheckOut');
    var rgA=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),1);
    var rgC=sh.getRange(1,3,sh.getLastRow(),1);
    var vA=rgA.getValues();
    var vC=rgC.getValues();
    for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
      if(vA[i][0]==item) {
        vC[i][0]='out_of_stock';
        break;
      }
    }
    rgC.setValues(vC);
  }
}
```

Comment: Good deal.  Glad to help.